# How to make an insert form and a table displaying data from database in a single view in MVC5 using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, crud

List and create in same view in asp.net mvc5 with EF
I need to display the data in grid after submitted users details:
simply I have

1. Form: name , city @Create
2. Table @Index

Comment: Have you considered using partial views for Display and Insert Form?

Comment: No, I am trying in razor syntax using in mvc